# Setting up a Tracker with Opentracker

Tags: networking, bittorrent

I'm trying to run my tracker for the first time. I'd followed the instructions on (https://erdgeist.org/arts/software/opentracker/) and when I run ./opentracker it seems to be working (no error or anything promtped). But when I try the following (so I can set my IP address and start the server):

./opentracker.debug -i 190.18.43.148 -p 6969

I get the following error:

Binding socket type TCP to address [190.18.43.148]:6969...socket_bind6_reuse: Cannot assign requested address

Would you let me know what am I doing wrong? Thanks!!

Comment: Try to run it without parameters, if that works, you probaly need to read up on how to configure and set the parameters properly. I found a thread with a similar issue on the forums http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2146944

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works perfectly with IP 0.0.0.0 but I don't think I'll be able to connect with anyone with that address... That's why I'm wondering how to cnofigure it with my own IP to make it run properly.. but got no clue

Comment: Can anybody help me please?